# "-STA -WindowStyle Hidden" Option not working with citrix

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, batch-file, citrix

i have a powershell application published to citrix. It simple executes a remote batch file Initiator.Bat which then executes apowershell script with following command, `Powershell \\server\Taskpad\Script.ps1`; then user gets a credential prompt.

Everything is working fine except the big ugly command window openning in the background which i dont want. So i used option "-STA -WindowStyle Hidden", but when i click the application , i does nothing , it closes automatically within a second and credential prompt is not displayed. that option works perfectly in normal windows environment. Please do let me know , what am i doing wrong and how to make it work in citrix?

Comment: Does it work as expected when using RDP? Also, is this a published / seamless app, or does the user get a full desktop?

Comment: Its a published seamless app , it works fine every-time else.